# Why is passport.serializeUser not a function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js

I've already been searching for almost one hour but I can not find the problem of my code, neither was I able to find a solution on inter and I even asked for help in other coding communities on Discord but no-one knows why I have such an error.

I've been trying to follow this tutorial https://mherman.org/blog/node-passport-and-postgres/#objectives to get to know the passport package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport

I have the following files

**userController.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as Path from 'path';
import passport = require('../../auth/local');



export const userLogIn = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    
    passport.default.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) { res.status(500).send('error'); }
        if (!user) { res.status(404).send('User not found!'); }
        if (user)
        {
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) { res.status(500).send('error'); }
                res.status(200).send('success!');
            });
        }
    });
    return;
}
```

**local.ts**

```
import * as passport from 'passport';
import passport_local = require('passport-local');
const LocalStrategy = passport_local.Strategy;

import init = require('../passport');
import { knex } from '../knex/knex';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

const options = {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
};

init.default();

export default passport.use(new LocalStrategy(options, (username, password, done) => {
    knex('accounts').where({userEmail: username}).first()
    .then((user) => {
        if (!user) return done(null, false)
        if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.userPassword)) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        else {
            return done(null, user);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => { return done(err); });
}));
```

And the file where I have the problem

**passport.ts**

```
import * as passport from 'passport';
import { knex } from './knex/knex';

export default function(){
    passport.serializeUser<any, any>(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        knex('accounts').where({userId: id}).first()
        .then((user) => { done(null, user) })
        .catch((err) => { done(err, null) });
    });
}
```

My error:

> TypeError: passport.serializeUser is not a function

I have @types installed and imported for passport, if I hover my mouse over the import of passport it shows it is imported from the @types folder.

I have no idea what can cause this.

And yes, one function is with 'function' and the other is with arrow because I tried changing it searching for the solution but nothing seem to work.

Comment: passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {done(null, user.id);
 }); , this works without '<any, any>' ? PS: I don't use typescript

Comment: @Mendes I had the same error before adding any, any so yeah, any any has no effect whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you're importing it the wrong way.

`import passport from "passport";` - should work according to the code sources

Comment: I thought all the imports are doing the same thing but differently syntax, it really works now, thanks:D